# What is the default cache value of Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, configuration, hardware, tuning

According to the [help page of Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options), `--cache value` defines

```
Megabytes of memory allocated to internal caching (default = 4096 mainnet full node, 128 light mode) (default: 1024)
```

I don't quite get it, is the default `4096` or `1024` when running with the defaults (i.e. fast sync, automatically switching to full mode later on)?

And is there a way I can check this (e.g. with the Geth JavaScript console)?

I'm asking because I assume I've got some [memory issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/k0our2/geth_causing_stall_on_cpu_ubuntu_20041_on_nuc/) on a Intel Pentium NUC with 8 GB of RAM. Maybe, if the default is 4 GB, it helps setting `--cache 1024` to avoid these memory issues.